# NSSlider without background

Tags: cocoa

When ever my NSSlider is displayed, it has a rounded rectangle background (see the linked image). I would like it to only have the bar and the knob drawn, not this background.

[image: NSSlider with grey background]

I have looked into subclassing NSSliderCell or NSSlider, but it seem that no matter what draw method I override this background will not go away. Is there anything I can do to get rid of this background, or are my only option to make my own control?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck the Bordered option in Xcode or you can set it to NO in code.

If that doesn't work you've got it inside an NSBox or something

Comment: There are no bordered option or property on NSSlider or NSSliderCell

Comment: Don't forget the inheritance chain. NSCell has the methods so NSSliderCell has it. I don't recall if it does anything. It could override the methods to do nothing. Try it